# Request signature failing for Alibaba Cloud API call

Tags: alibaba-cloud

I tried creating a method in Postman and got really close but am having issues with the signature. We are trying to query the IP ranges for VPCs to add to a WAF rule, in order to allow traffic to a secure application.

Postman allows a pre-request script, in Javascript, and supports a handful of included JS libraries, including CryptoJS.

The code here creates exactly the request that Ali Cloud says needs to be signed. It signs with HMAC-SHA1 from CryptoJS and encodes to base 64.

All of the variables are included in the request parameters. I'm not sure what else it could be complaining about.

```
var dateIso = new Date().toISOString();

var randomString = function(length) {
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    }
    return text;
}

var accesskeyid = "LTAI4GC7VEijsm5bV3zwcZxZ"
var action = "DescribePublicIPAddress"
var format = "XML"
var regionid = "cn-shanghai-eu13-a01"
var signaturemethod = "HMAC-SHA1"
var signaturenonce = randomString(16)
var signatureversion = "1.0"
var timestamp = dateIso.replace(/:/gi, "%253A")
var version = "2016-04-28"

pm.environment.set("AccessKeyId", accesskeyid)
pm.environment.set("Action", action)
pm.environment.set("Format", format)
pm.environment.set("RegionID", regionid)
pm.environment.set("SignatureMethod", signaturemethod)
pm.environment.set("SignatureNonce", signaturenonce)
pm.environment.set("SignatureVersion", signatureversion)
pm.environment.set("Timestamp", dateIso)
pm.environment.set("Version", version)

var request = "GET&amp;%2F&amp;" + "AccessKeyID%3D" + accesskeyid + "%26Action%3D" + action + "%26Format%3D" + format + "%26RegionID%3D" + regionid + "%26SignatureMethod%3D" + signaturemethod + "%26SignatureNonce%3D" + signaturenonce + "%26SignatureVersion%3D" + signatureversion + "%26Timestamp%3D" + timestamp + "%26Version%3D" + version

pm.environment.set("Request", request)

var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(request, "spwH5dNeEm4t4dlpqvYWVGgf7aEAxB&")
var base64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash)
var encodesig = encodeURIComponent(base64)
pm.environment.set("Signature", encodesig);

console.log(base64)
console.log(request)
```

The console output shows:

```
Signature: XbVi12iApzZ0rRgJLBv0ytJJ0LY=

Parameter string to be signed: 
GET&amp;%2F&amp;AccessKeyID%3DLTAI4GC7VEijsm5bV3zwcZvC%26Action%3DDescribePublicIPAddress%26Format%3DXML%26RegionID%3Dcn-shanghai-eu13-a01%26SignatureMethod%3DHMAC-SHA1%26SignatureNonce%3DiP1QJtbasQNSOxVY%26SignatureVersion%3D1.0%26Timestamp%3D2020-06-01T15%253A38%253A12.266Z%26Version%3D2016-04-28

Request sent:
GET https://vpc.aliyuncs.com/?AccessKeyID=LTAI4GC7VEijsm5bV3zwcZvC&Action=DescribePublicIPAddress&Format=XML&RegionID=cn-shanghai-eu13-a01&SignatureMethod=HMAC-SHA1&SignatureNonce=iP1QJtbasQNSOxVY&SignatureVersion=1.0&Timestamp=2020-06-01T15:38:12.266Z&Version=2016-04-28&Signature=XbVi12iApzZ0rRgJLBv0ytJJ0LY%3D

Response Received:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><RequestId>B16D216F-56ED-4D16-9CEC-633C303F2B61</RequestId><HostId>vpc.aliyuncs.com</HostId><Code>IncompleteSignature</Code><Message>The request signature does not conform to Aliyun standards. server string to sign is:GET&amp;%2F&amp;AccessKeyID%3DLTAI4GC7VEijsm5bV3zwcZvC%26Action%3DDescribePublicIPAddress%26Format%3DXML%26RegionID%3Dcn-shanghai-eu13-a01%26SignatureMethod%3DHMAC-SHA1%26SignatureNonce%3DiP1QJtbasQNSOxVY%26SignatureVersion%3D1.0%26Timestamp%3D2020-06-01T15%253A38%253A12.266Z%26Version%3D2016-04-28</Message><Recommend><![CDATA[https://error-center.aliyun.com/status/search?Keyword=IncompleteSignature&source=PopGw]]></Recommend></Error>
```

When I check the "server string to sign" from the response and the parameter string that was signed in a compare, they are identical.

It looks like everything is built as needed but the signature is still barking. Guessing I missed something simple but haven't found it yet.

Note: The `accesskeyID` and key posted are for example purposes and not a real account so this code will not copy and paste to execute in Postman.

PS - I learned quite a bit from the other few threads on this topic, which is how I got to this point. akostadinov was super helpful on another thread.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have double encoded &. I have implemented other Alibaba Cloud REST APIs successfully. Could you please check this.

Following is the expected string to sign format:

```
GET&%2F&AccessKeyId%3Dtestid&Action%3DDescribeVpcs&Format%3DXML&
SignatureMethod%3DHMAC-SHA1&SignatureNonce%3D3ee8c1b8-83d3-44af-a94f-4e0ad82fd6cf&SignatureVersion%3D1.0&TimeStamp%3D2016-02-23T12%253A46%
253A24Z&Version%3D2014-05-15
```

Comment: Are you sure that the string to sign contains `&` vs `%26` ? because according to their docs they requested `HTTPMethod + & + percentEncode("/") + & + percentEncode(CanonicalizedQueryString)` meaning all the params of the URL (`CanonicalizedQueryString` w/o `Signature`) should be encoded

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but as this is the first result when googling for the `IncompleteSignature` error, I thought I might comment and hopefully save someone else the grief I have been through.

For me, the subtle detail that I missed in the official documentation [here](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/25492.htm?spm=a2c63.p38356.879954.6.4d21798d6x6VS4#EcsApiSignature) is that the key used for the signature requires an ampersand `&` to be added to the end, before being used.

As soon as I caught that, everything else worked perfectly.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Can you specify what key are talking here? Secret Key or Access Key?

Comment: `Note When you calculate the signature, the key value specified by RFC 2104 is your AccessKeySecret with an ampersand (&), which has an ASCII value of 38. For more information, see Obtain an AccessKey pair. `

Comment: I had the `&` at the end of the secret but Q1: can you show how's your string to sign looks like before you encode & after ? and if `SignatureNonce` can be used as a random number vs `uuid` style ?

Comment: The example on this page (https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/en/elastic-compute-service/latest/request-signatures#EcsApiSignature) has steb-by-step values that you can use to verify your code. And yes, the nonce is just a string: format is irrelevant.